# Searching inside archives for specific files and patterns

Tags: grep, osx, archive

Is it possible to grep inside a bunch of archives with regular expressions on both the names of the files they contain and the contents of those files? I would like to know which files in which archives match the pattern. I'm on OS X, if it matters.

Comment: Normally, you can use `zgrep`, but you must add more details for your question to clarify it.

Comment: I tried to rephrase for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use more expressive `grep`-style file patterns:

```
tar -OT <(tar -tf /path/to/file.tar | grep 'FILE_PATTERN') -xf /path/to/file.tar \
    | grep 'CONTENT_PATTERN'
```

`-O` specifies the output to be `stdout`, and `-T` specifies a file containing names to extract, when used in conjunction with `-x`.

If simpler [pathname expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs) is good enough, you can replace the process substitution (`<( ... )`) with a simpler `echo` line, this avoids having to read run `tar` on the file twice:

```
tar -OT <(echo 'FILE_PATTERN') -xf /path/to/file.tar \
    | grep 'CONTENT_PATTERN'
```

If you want to also see the filenames, add the `-v` flag (personally I will go for `-xvf`), but then you'll also need to modify `CONTENT_PATTERN` to grep for the filenames again. <s>I'll leave this as an exercise for the reader...</s>

It gets a bit tricky, and you'll probably have to use `awk` for a little more output processing... The matching filenames will be displayed per line, so unfortunately there's no clear-cut delimiter here. *Assuming filenames will not be repeated as contents*:

```
tar ... | awk '/^FILLE_AWK_PATTERN$/{f=$0;next}...'
```

That sets the `awk` variable `f` to be every new filename encountered *and skips to the next line*. Then,

```
tar ... | awk '...$f&&/CONTENT_AWK_PATTERN/{print $f;$f=""}'
```

Once we see a matching line, we print `$f` *and reset our filename* until the next file is 'encountered'.

Putting it together:

```
tar -OT <(echo 'FILE_PATTERN') -xf /path/to/file.tar \
    | awk '/^FILLE_AWK_PATTERN$/{f=$0;next};$f&&/CONTENT_AWK_PATTERN/{print $f;$f=""}'
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I ended up using `acat` from `atools` instead of tar and piped to grep + uniq

Comment: @Emre feel free to share your solution too! :)

Comment: `for file in *.zip ; do acat $file foo | grep bar | uniq | sed -e 's/^/'$file' /g' ; done`